# High Tech Supermax dwarfing Tartarus

Tags: magic, nanotechnology, control

**Scenario**

Set in present day on a secluded island inaccessible by land and air, due to the perilous weather conditions, there is a sophisticated fortress filled to the brim with deadly traps and thick composite wall reinforced with di-magical material to serve as a temporary holiday resort for very disruptive, talented inmates. Okay I'll cut straight to the chase...

**Confinement Protocols**

1. All inmates will have to put on di-magical body restraints, this material emits its own unique magic to keep out other magic in short no external magical forces can hope to penetrate it or even manipulate it due to its uniqueness. All inmates are injected with tens of billions of nano transmitters for tracking purpose only.
2. The inmate is dropped into a 3 cubic meter air-tight compartment, also decorated with di-magical material, which we then will cover and seal completely. The compartment is equipped with self recycling air and water supply and there are sufficient rations to last even a dinosaur hundreds of years. Note that there is a tiny camera to monitor the inside condition real time and most of them will probably be released once they have served their sentence in full.
3. As for the uncooperative inmates. We will impale them literally against the walls as they will have to use their own magic to heal or be left for dead(just kidding no worries I already have medics on standby).
4. All the compartments are then submerged into a giant pool of sulpheric acid or fluoroantimonic acid(no kidding).
5. (Under construction)

**Question**

**Q1**: My concern is regarding those who are gifted with the abilities manipulate dimensions and/or time. So ladies and gentlemen how do I satisfy my fifth containment? I'm a man of my word so once they have fulfilled their term. I'll allow them to leave this supermax alive and probably maimed  (they have to be conscious throughout the stay due to self reflection)

The easy way out is to apply magic to combat magic but my supermax has a title to keep.

**Bonus Question** (Optional)

**Q2**: We also have fallen demigods and cambions so how do I make rooms for them? 
(This question is not for the faint of heart as we merely adopted magic but they are born with it!)

**Note**

Di-magical materials do not negate (cancel out) magical properties, but simply limit (hold back) magic, hence the targeted magic does not lose power over time due to being in close proximity with di-magical substances (no dilution).

Time travelers and walking teleporters are known to vanish into thin air leaving no trace behind except the body restraints are intact. Even those subjected to Vlad's treatment (impaled with di-magic) are prone to escape using spatial magic.

Do not attempt Q2 unless you have answered Q1, Q2 is not mandatory.

Comment: How would they be exercising their time and dimension manipulating abilities if they are in restraints designed to prohibit their magic?

Comment: @Cort Ammon The restraints is not antimagic but rather works like a sun block, so I imagine they can teleport their own body to a different time or place. So in short their power cannot extend beyond their body and also there is no antimagic in existence in this world.

Comment: What sort of magic do the wardens have access too? Do they have (non-fallen) demi-gods on their side?

Comment: @Amziraro I'm a little xenophobic and relies heavily on technology to spank these arrogant bast***s and keep them in check also this hi-tech facility runs entirely on automation to eliminate human errors. So there should be no mere mortals on the island beside these freaks... you are safe to assume all wardens run on battery.

Comment: @Amziraro I'll allow part-timer if Herucle or his friends are interested free meals and lodging provided and can enjoy dental benefit and entitled to max 20 days worth of annual leaves, so what's your roster?

Comment: @user6760 Sorry answer took longer than I thought it would. Essentially, build the Supermax with help from friendly Demi-gods. If you can wrangle it hire Zeus, et al to help build it.

Comment: @Amziraro thanks for this excellent answer I'll collate as many answers before accepting if you don't mind. Unfortunately God usually ignores my prayer so probably will never bother to pick up my call, that aside can you quote me 9 trillions supermax and I expect a huge discount for purchasing in bulk.

Comment: Re: collating answers, That's good practice! Someone almost certainly has better ideas than me. Shame about Zeus though ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24829/discussion-between-amziraro-and-user6760).

Comment: You mean Spellhold?

Comment: @Serban Tanasa Bingo! this unique asylum only house deviants not more (divine beings) not less (flesh and blood).

Comment: How unusual to mix [tag:magic] and [tag:nanotechnology]! "Present day" does not include either, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep your dimension/time shifting inmates in, build a multidimensional prison in multiple time streams. Essentially, if Alice can walk through walls by travelling to dimension XYZ then you should also build walls in XYZ so she can't escape. Similarly with Time, build the prison a long time ago and make sure it will exist in the future.

This is how The Original Merlin built his Supermax (for big evil baddies) in the Dresden Files:

> He created the magical prison Demonreach by building it once, at five different times, all at the same time. And he put in place a Failsafe: a fire that would kill them rather than release them.

From [the Dresden Files wikia.](http://dresdenfiles.wikia.com/wiki/The_Original_Merlin)

Get some help from a few friendly demigods to send the whole building back further than any one time traveller could go on their own.

Essentially if the abilities of each Time Traveller/Dimension Skipper are limited, build your prison to exploit those weaknesses.

**Example 1:** Lets say a Time Traveller (call him Bob) can travel only decade into the past or future. That is pretty ridiculously overpowered for a regular human in my opinion, but lets run with it. Bob can travel back a decade, but finds that the prison was already around a decade ago. He travels can't travel further back, because he's not that powerful.

**Example 2:** A different Time Traveller (Carol) can travel into the past or future, 10 years *at a time* but then has to rest before going back further. She ends up back in prison 10 years ago, but before she can go back further she is caught by either the past warden (who saw her arrive on a security camera) or the present warden (who saw her leave) and the local friendly registered time travel agent.

**Example 3:** Demigod Dave is absurdly strong (bends steel with a pinky or something), a Time Traveller, and can walk through walls. The local friendly Demigods don't like him and have no problem helping the warden out in keeping him contained. The prison should exist for longer (both past and future) than he can reasonably travel, and the multidimensional walls should be able to keep him in.

**Example 4:** Edward the Archmage can do all these things, (Time Travel, Strong, Dimension Walk, etc) but uses magic. Make the multidimensional walls out of Di-magical metal.

---

If those those tracking nanites can detect when time travel occurs, they can also be used as a beacon. They could also leave a trail (by, ah, squirting out of the body) which would help to track any escapees. Of course you can probably weaponise them to disable esacapees by (eg) pinching some important nerves, producing a sedative, etc.

Contract some Demigods to build the prison in the past out of heavy blocks of Di-magical matter. Make sure the prison is multidimensional from the start so no-one can escape by walking through walls. Your robot wardens can easily contract some friendly powerful individuals to help retrieve inmates from the past/future.

Answer (score 1):

**For the time travelers.**

Put a clock inside their body.

Once the clock has ticked by the required time then you let them out. They can slow down or speed up whatever they like but until they have subjectively experienced the time they're sentenced to, they don't get out.

**For the teleporters.**

Put a dead man's switched bomb inside their body.

If they try to teleport out of prison, the magical bomb, which was only restrained from blowing up by the unique properties of the prison, will explode. Alternatively you can just amputate their head, keep it alive with the magic of the prison, if they teleport out they probably only get their head and in either case they rapidly die. Their walls should also span all dimensions.

The simple answer, as for many things in life, is radical surgery.

---

The cambions and demi-gods will require some divine holding magic. This is a common trope in fantasy.

Comment: I don't understand how putting a clock inside a time traveler can stop him from using his ability? I agree with your answer to Q2 an eye for a tooth...lol

Comment: @user6760 It keeps track of their subjective time. Combined with the teleportation protection, it ensures that they experience the proper time sentence.

Comment: your counter-measures are the finest I've ever seen however let's focus on prevention for now. Meaning these deviants must feel and recognise that they are serving a sentence behind bars, freedom is beyond their reach at the moment unless of course either completing the term or exchanging for reduced stay with good behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The Olympian gods thought chaining the Titan Prometheus to a mountain and having savage eagles tearing at his liver would be distracting enough that he would stay in place for all time, so maybe we can take a page from Zeus:

Each cell containing a time traveller or teleporter will be equipped with the equivalent of a "white noise" generator to cause distraction, make them lose focus and nullify any cues they might need to enable their abilities. The British used "the white room" as a successful technique against PIRA terrorists in the 1970's; people brought in for questioning would become quite disorientated after even a short time in the white room, and much easier to question without the use of what would be considered torture, "enhanced interrogation" or even human rights violations. (the "white room" was a room isolated from all outside stimulus, brightly lit and with a white noise generator constantly going. Prisoners waiting in the white room lost track of passage of time quite rapidly, and interrogators added to the deception by ensuring there were no clues to the passage of time outside either; for example the same interrogator would always question the prisoner, the were fed at irregular intervals and so on).

The second possibility is to fight magic with superscience. If you could create the conditions of an extreme warping of space-time near the cell, then the cell would be effectively in the same condition as if it were near the event horizon of a black hole. The extreme warping of space-time should prevent successful use of time travel or teleportation (time travel in particular, due to relativistic time dilation), and if worst comes to worst, the cell can be in a quasi stable configuration and the inmate told that any attempt to tinker with space or time will cause the cell to fall past the event horizon, making the sentence permanent exile from this universe, with no appeal. (If you are living in a world where criminal have the sorts of powers outlined, then hiring "Dr Science" to work for the Department of Corrections is also quite likely. After all, how did the cops catch these people in the first place?).

Gods and demi gods derive their power from their worshippers, either directly (the more people who pray to you the more powerful that you are) or indirectly (your strength comes from the offerings of the worshippers. Worshippers who offer choice cuts of meat will get a stronger god than those who offer soup bones). Since worshippers on the mainland can still provide power to the imprisoned deities, then the prison guards will need to become worshippers of even more powerful deities, with the advantage of being much "closer" to the scene of the action. There needs to be a bit of thought involved, competing deities from the same pantheon *might* work (Athena, goddess of wisdom and strategy, works tirelessly against Ares, god of battle and slaughter), while the current "best" defense against pagan deities is the One God (although since He works in mysterious ways, this might not be the best choice for the prison warden to make).

Comment: How do you address deviants with spatial or chrono powers?

Comment: Section 2 of the answer; put them in an extreme gravity well or area of warped space.

Comment: I must say never in a million years I can imagine a sorcerer supreme undergoes spaghettification that's probably dwarf the most powerful disintegration spell ever! science 1 magic 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you can build nanites, you can build a fairly sophisticated brain implant.

A brain implant that detects an attempt to use a special ability and interrupts it within few milliseconds with an electric shock directly to the brain would make using such abilities difficult. Set it so that the after effect is nausea and most will stop trying to use their abilities, possibly permanently due to conditioning.

Similar blocks could be set for aggression and lying. Once inmates are conditioned to avoid lying, you can improve security by simply regularly asking them to tell you of any escape plans.

Any re-education could be enforced by wiring the implants to the reward system. You could simply make the inmates happy to be in your prison and cooperate with your efforts.

And obviously the implant would also have small explosive charge to discourage tampering. And an ability to detect if it is within the prison.

You can also turn up this a notch to turn the inmates to functional zombies. Most people looking back at that kind of prison time would decide to not break law again in your jurisdiction.

Comment: Good recommendations infect everyone in the every world including Asgard and make supermax obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

How about crafting a pocket universe with spacetime properties that don't allow anything inside to affect it. The bubble travels along its own meta-time dimension, and there is nothing anyone can do until it comes out the other end. A time traveller inside would travel to the past within the pocket universe, which has no real effect other than to lose his rations.

Note that the time spent out here has nothing to do with it, so 60 years inside will take no time. You won't need huge warehousing facilities, and nobody on the outside can help him escape since no time passes to the helper.

Spacetime itself is the ultimate prison.  Creating a spacetime without the same features of the principle universe (e.g. being able to create and access other universes) is like a secure compartment in computer software engineering.

Comment: You mean trapping the subject in another realm? how does it work I know there are many fictious accounts whereby users got lost in a different time or dimensions... ultimately I still need them to reflect on their mistakes and turn over a new leaf.

Comment: How does it work? Same way as time travel and extra - dimensional travel.